# Can't install aspose-total-net Pypi

Tags: python, package, pypi, aspose

I'm trying to install aspose.total trial version using Pypi but keep getting stuck with this error:

```
C:\Users\me>pip install aspose-total-Net --no-cache-dir
Collecting aspose-total-Net
  Downloading aspose-total-net-22.6.0.tar.gz (4.2 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zmgd3moj\aspose-total-net_cf18cc193096459a972e2cca196954e6\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Am I the only on with this problem?

Comment: Aspose.Total package includes individual Aspose packages. You can try installing the packages you are interested in individually. For example https://pypi.org/project/aspose-words/

Comment: I got this instead:
```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1766]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\azlan>pip install Aspose.Slides
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 21.11 Requires-Python >=3.5,<3.10; 22.1 Requires-Python >=3.5,<3.10; 22.4.0 Requires-Python >=3.5,<3.10
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Aspose.Slides (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Aspose.Slides

C:\Users\azlan>
```

Comment: So is my Python version to high?

Comment: And what's in 3.10 that aspose don't support?

Comment: It worked for Words though...

Comment: It specifically said in https://docs.aspose.com/slides/python-net/system-requirements/ that only 3.5 or greater is required! is this a bug?

Comment: Thank you for reporting the issue. I work as a Support Developer at Aspose and added a ticket with ID SLIDESPYNET-18 to our issue tracking system. Our development team will investigate the case. We will notify you when the issue is resolved if you want. As I can see, you have already managed to install Aspose.Total.

Comment: Yes please post a comment here when the issue is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, Aspose.Slides for Python does not support Python 3.10 yet. It has been planned for Aspose.Slides for Python 22.6. You can get help with Aspose.Slides faster on our [free forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/slides/).

Comment: For now I'll just use miniconda with python 3.9 which works exceeding well!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install Aspose slides via the `--ignore-requires-python` flag. And as @Alexy Noskov said aspose total is just all the packages together. So my problem is solved. Thanks @Alexy Noskov !

Comment: I guess right now is just the matter of how well aspose.Slides will work.

Comment: Got stuck at `import aspose.slides` returning `KeyError: 'aspose.slides'` just for your info